# Could not find an overload for '^' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift

```
func squareArea(side:Double) -> Double {
    return side ^ 2
}
```

I get the error:

```
could not find an overload for '^' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

I've also tried

```
func squareArea(side:Double) -> Double {
    return Double(side ^ 2)
}
```

and

```
func squareArea(side:Double) -> Double {
    return side ^ Double(2)
}
```

but

```
func squareArea(side:Double) -> Double {
    return side * side
}
```

works fine.  What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function for that:

```
func squareArea(side:Double) -> Double {
    return pow(side, 2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

^ Is the XOR operator not the "power" operator. [See here and search "XOR".](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)

> The bitwise XOR operator, or “exclusive OR operator” (^), compares the bits of two numbers. The operator returns a new number whose bits are set to 1 where the input bits are different and are set to 0 where the input bits are the same:

```
let firstBits: UInt8 = 0b00010100
let otherBits: UInt8 = 0b00000101
let outputBits = firstBits ^ otherBits
```